# cannot get the url as get parameter from index.php using htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

heres my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [NC,L]
```

the index.php file is at the same depth as the .htaccess file but when I call

```
$url = $_GET['url'];
```

in the index.php. there is a warning saying there is no index called url in the $_GET superglobal.

Please help me

Comment: You could get this information direct from the $_SERVER array without using any rewrites.

Comment: change [NC,L] to [QSA,L] and check

Comment: How do you want your URL to look like.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty i changed it to no effect

Comment: @ShikharSubedi: For which URL it is NOT working?

Comment: if the redirection does not works properly, try replacing the rule by `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?url=$1 [NC,L]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was not my htaccess file but I had not enabled mod_rewrite in my system.

enabling mod_rewrite solved the problem. So,

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
sudo service apache2 restart
```

This solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

That's when you go directly to the url "http://example.com/" or  "http://example.com/index.php" .

To fix this you can check if 'url' exists before using it:

```
if (isset($_GET['url']))
  $url = $_GET['url'];
else
{
  // do nothing, or die()
  die('no direct access allowed');
}
```